# Footnote line number

Tags: footnotes

I am using LaTeX to prepare critical edition in DEVNAGARI. I want to set footnotes with reference to text-line numbers **on each page** (not putting super script number exactly on the top of a word in text). How to set and what is the package.

Comment: Probably the [`lineo` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/lineno) can help you.

Comment: Please provide a MWE (http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) that demonstrates what you need. I understand your question, but it takes too much time to write everything on my own.

Comment: Without an example that reproduces the problem, this question is likely to be closed during the 'Answer the unanswered' event tomorrow. Please edit your question if you still need help.